# Python Parsing Month, year from datetime64[ns]

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a pandas datetime object,  df['issue_date'] and I would like to create an object which contains only the month and year of the object, with a '0' in front of all months with single digits.  All years are > 2000
I've tried:

```
[In]
import datetime

df['issue_year'] =  pd.DatetimeIndex(lcd['issue_date']).year.astype(int)
df['issue_month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(lcd['issue_date']).month.astype(int)
df['issue_MMYY'] = df['issue_month']*1000+df['issue_year'] % 2000
```

But this feels (very) kludgy and slow, and also does not pad the 0 in front.   In general, date time objects give me fits....can anyone help with something more elegant?

Comment: how does `lcd['issue_date']` look

Comment: There is also a convenient way to extract information about `DateTime`. This can be done by using `dt`. For example it is possible to get the year and month numbers simply like this `lcd.issue_date.dt.year` `lcd.issue_date.dt.month`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lcd = pd.DataFrame({'issue_date': pd.date_range('2015-09-01', periods=4, freq='Q')})
lcd.issue_date.apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%m%Y'))
```

The result:

```
0    092015
1    122015
2    032016
3    062016
```

Comment: Given that the OP named the column `issue_MMYY`, I assume the format should probably be %m%y.